# given $\neg(a=0)$,then prove that there exists an $x$ such that $ax+b>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $\neg(a=0)$,then it is obvious that:

$-\frac{b}{a}>0$ or $-\frac{b}{a}<0$ or $-\frac{b}{a}=0$

But then from trichotomy law in real Nos we have:

$x>0$ or $x<0$ or $x=0$

Hence we have : $x>-\frac{b}{a}$ or  $x<-\frac{b}{a}$ or  $x=-\frac{b}{a}$

Also $a>0$ OR $a<0$ since $\neg(a=0)$

Thus since  $x>-\frac{b}{a}$ and $a>0$ we have $ax+b>0$

So we can conclude that there exists an x such that $ax+b>0$

Is that proof correct?

Comment: Your proof has gaps. For example, just because $x>0$ you cannot claim that $x>-b/a$.

Comment: you also cannot be sure that x>0 .e.g.if a=b=-1.

Answer (score 0):

If $a>0$ then $a x+b>0 \iff a x>-b \iff x>-b/a$. So if $a>0$ and $x=1-a/b $ then $a x+b>0$....... If $a<0$ then $a x +b>0 \iff -a x-b<0 \iff |a|x-b<0 \iff |a|x<-b \iff x<-b/|a|.$ So if $a<0$ and $x=-1-b/|a|$ then $a x +b>0.$